# Format date with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am the problem in defining the output of "date" . I would like that the past value for the variable is dd / mm / yyyy. The problem is who is going 2016-05-11T19 : 23: 34.399Z "

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/LRnkwtiIFearwbiDB5Qm?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to display the date with the mentioned format? Then you could use `{{dt | date: 'dd / MM / yyyy'}}`. MM in uppercase!!

Answer (score 2):

Add a date filter and required format.

```
 {{dt | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DDDepd8uwpzdBlGgxpuk?p=preview

@Yehudi Mekhael, if you want `dt` to be in that format and pass as parameter then you can do something.

```
var dt = $filter('date')(dt, 'MMM dd yyyy');
```

But now `dt` is not a date object, it's a string.

Comment: Should be 'dd / MM / yyyy' as pointed out by @AWolf because mm = minutes

Comment: @mhodges Done! Thanks

Comment: I want the variable "dt" is already in the standard dd/MM/yyyy. It's because I 'm going to pass this variable as a parameter , then it must be in this format

Answer (score 2):

Just use like this

```
{{dt | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

Comment: Should be 'dd/MM/yyyy' as pointed out by @AWolf because mm = minutes

Comment: I want the variable "dt" is already in the standard dd/MM/yyyy. It's because I 'm going to pass this variable as a parameter , then it must be in this format